# Get destination_payment from transfer in Stripe API

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm working with the Stripe API, specifically in Python but this question is generally about API endpoints so could be applied to any language. I am creating a programmatic transfer to a connected account as explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create), and in a demo below:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = 'rk_test_xxxxxxx'
acct_id = 'acct_xxxxx'
resp = stripe.Transfer.create(
    amount=100,
    currency='usd',
    destination=acct_id,
    description='Test Transfer 1'
)
```

Then, as is shown in the API, I am able to retrieve from this transfer the `destination_payment` object, which is what actually shows up in the Payments feed for a connected account:

```
dest_pmt = resp['destination_payment']
```

So this is the object our partners would see. But then, I want to be able to modify that destination payment object--specifically, to be able to edit the description and metadata of it. (Currently, the description just shows up as the value of `dest_pmt`, and there is no metadata.) But the ID for the destination payment comes in the form `py_xxxxx` and I don't know what endpoint to use to retrieve an object in that form. When I reached out to Stripe support, they suggested that I could retrieve/modify (and I use retrieve for this example just for simplicity) it using the payment intent endpoint, as such:

```
resp_2 = stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(
    dest_pmt,
    stripe_account=acct_id
)
```

But I got the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Request req_xxxxxx: No such payment_intent: 'py_xxxxxxxxx'
```

Also, I am using Standard Connected Accounts for reference, but I don't think it would make a huge difference. Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea with the retrieval using the `Stripe-Account` header, but the `py_123` objects from transfers and destination charges are actually Charge type objects. You can retrieve them using the Charge `/retrieve` API ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve?lang=python)):

```
charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(
  dest_pmt, # 'py_123'
  stripe_account=acct_id
)
```